# How can I simplify my geometric calculation?

Tags: equation-solving, performance-tuning, geometry

Here is a math problem I am dealing with right now:

> Given ellipse $C$: $x^2/a^2 + y^2/b^2=1$ ($a>b>0$). Ellipse $C$ passes through the point $P$: $(1,3/2)$, and has eccentricity $e=1/2$. Given line $\ell$: $x=4$. $\overline{AB}$ is the chord that intersects line $\ell$ on point $M$, and $F$ is the right focus of ellipse $C$. The slopes of $\overline{PA}$, $\overline{PB}$, and $\overline{PM}$ are respectively $k_1$, $k_2$, and $k_3$. Is there a constant $\lambda$ that satisfies $k_1 + k_2 =\lambda k_3$? If there is, please calculate $\lambda$.

How can use the last results into next input?

```
Solve[{x^2/4 + y^2/3 == 1, y == k (x - 1)}, {x, y}]
```

> ```
> {x -> (2 (2 k^2 - 3 Sqrt[1 + k^2]))/(3 + 4 k^2), 
>  y -> -k + (4 k^3)/(3 + 4 k^2) - (6 k Sqrt[1 + k^2])/(3 + 4 k^2)}, 
> {x -> (2 (2 k^2 + 3 Sqrt[1 + k^2]))/(3 + 4 k^2), 
>  y -> -k + (4 k^3)/(3 + 4 k^2) + (6 k Sqrt[1 + k^2])/(3 + 4 k^2)}}
> ```

```
A = 
  {(2 (2 k^2 - 3 Sqrt[1 + k^2]))/(3 + 4 k^2), 
   -k + (4 k^3)/(3 + 4 k^2) - (6 k Sqrt[1 + k^2])/(3 + 4 k^2)};
B = 
  {(2 (2 k^2 + 3 Sqrt[1 + k^2]))/(3 + 4 k^2), 
   -k + (4 k^3)/(3 + 4 k^2) + (6 k Sqrt[1 + k^2])/(3 + 4 k^2)};
M = {4, 3 k};
P = {1, 3/2};
Simplify[k1 = (A[[2]] - P[[2]])/(A[[1]] - P[[1]]), k ∈ Reals]
Simplify[k2 = (B[[2]] - P[[2]])/(B[[1]] - P[[1]])]
Simplify[k3 = (M[[2]] - P[[2]])/(M[[1]] - P[[1]])]
Simplify[k1 + k2]
```

> ```
> (3 + 2 k + 4 k^2 + 4 k Sqrt[1 + k^2])/(2 + 4 Sqrt[1 + k^2])
>
> (3 + 2 k + 4 k^2 - 4 k Sqrt[1 + k^2])/(2 - 4 Sqrt[1 + k^2])
>
> -(1/2) + k
>
> -1 + 2 k
> ```

How can I use the result of the last and put it in the next input?

Comment: Can you perhaps explain what you're trying to do with a line and an ellipse?

Comment: The line indicates that a focus is at (1,0). That does not seem correct.

Comment: @J.M.willbebacksoon. It's a math problem I am dealing  with right now. Ellipse C: x 2    /a 2     + y 2    /b 2    =1 (a>b>0). Ellipse C pass through point P (1,3/2), Eccentricity e=1/2. Line l: x=4. AB is the chord that  intersect with line l on point M, And F is the right foci of ellipse C. The slopes of PA ,PB, PM are respectively k 1    , k 2    , k 3     . Is there a constant λ that meets k 1     + k 2    =λ k 3     ? If there is , please calculate λ

Comment: Please include that description in your question.

Comment: Alright. @J.M.willbebacksoon

Comment: @J.M.willbebacksoon I am having trouble edit this. It always pop up my post appears to contain code that is not properly formatted as code. Please indent all code by 4 spaces using the code toolbar button or the CTRL+K keyboard shortcut.

Comment: OK, I've added the problem description for you; edit it if there is anything I missed. (I also removed the diagram inserted by another user since it no longer looks related to your problem.)

Comment: @J.M.willbebacksoon, Thank you very much

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[image]

```
M = {4, 3 k};
P = {1, 3/2};
{A, B} = Values@Solve[{x^2/4 + y^2/3 == 1, y == k (x - 1)}, {x, y}]
slope[A_, B_] := 1/Divide @@ (B - A);
{k1, k2, k3} = slope @@@ {{A, P}, {B, P}, {M, P}} // FullSimplify
FullSimplify[k1 + k2]
```

[image]